# CLOC --diff and --exclude-dir don't seem to work together

Tags: cloc

I am trying to compare two directories with multiple subfolders. This is my CLOC script:

cloc-1.76.exe --diff test_initial test_latest --timeout 60 --exclude-dir=ZC_DATA --out=results.txt

Both folders have a **ZC_DATA** directory. In test_initial it is empty, in test_latest has several C and XML files, therefore lots of code to count.

What I am experiencing is that with or without the switch **exclude-dir=ZC_DATA** I am getting exactly the same results, no difference at all.

I need a way to include or exclude this folder in order to get different results.
Please advise.

Regards,
M.R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a straight count of one of the input directories, for example,

```
cloc-1.76.exe --timeout 60 --exclude-dir=ZC_DATA --out=results.txt test_latest
```

with and without `--exclude-dir=ZC_DATA` do the counts change?  Repeat the two invocations with the second directory, `test_initial`, and report if there are differences there as well.

Comment: Thanks AlDanial, mystery solved: I needed to increase timeout in order to get the exclude switch to work correctly. By the way, can you include in the output file a message like "Warning: timeout occurred during count" ? So that one can know straight away there was a problem and the count is inaccurate?

Comment: Also: can you implement something like --diff-timeout 0? Setting a zero timeout to tell the program to use an indeterminate amount of time in order to get the calculations right.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion with commit https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc/commit/fc96eb49d96323bc87fdb3ee62bc71c91dffe15b

Answer (score -1):

I'm trying to execute a `cloc` command with `--diff` AND `--exclude-list-file` and the files including in .clocignore are not ignored in the result.

Here the cmd:

```
os.system{'cloc --diff {} {} --exclude-list-file=.clocignore --by-file --out={} --csv'.format (directory1, directory2, output.loc)}
```

*.clocignore* file content:

```
/tmp/workspace/directory2/myfile.cpp
```

NOTE: this particular file (*myfile.cpp*) appears in directory2 but it does not exist in directory1.

If diff directory1 - directory2 is not successfully because some files in  directory1 do not exist, the result are: the lines counted in directory2, which it is fine!

BUT, 
it does not exclude the files contained in ..clocignore

why the --exclude-list-file=.clocignore is not working in this scenario?
Thanks,

Comment: seems like it's a question on its own? maybe post it separately and not as an answer?